# ol3 - calculate real meters in epgs 3857

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I use `ol3` as a map service.

I have made a `linestring` with two points with coordinates : `[[0,0],[0,1000]]` and calculated the distance using the vincenty formula. This resulted in 1000 meter, what is accurate.

But when i made another `linestring` for example `[[4052627,3971934],[4052627,3972934]]` vincenty distance was around 850 meters.

I dont know what i forgot here. Any way to correct that? I want to calculate epgs:3857 meters (units) for a given real distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After alot of search I've found this PDF document:

[Web Mercator:
Non-Conformal, Non-Mercator](http://www.hydrometronics.com/downloads/Web%20Mercator%20-%20Non-Conformal,%20Non-Mercator%20(notes).pdf)

There is something called `Point Scale Factor` - according to the way web Mercator is projected - which has tow values, not one like normal Mercator ,  `North/South Scale Factor` and `East/West Scale Factor`.

in my program I've ignored the `East/West Scale Factors` because it's to much small.

Once I've calculated the scale factor the real distance is almost equal to `scale_factor * epgs_3857_distence`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ol.sphere.haversineDistance](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Sphere.html#haversineDistance):

```
  var c1 = [4052627, 3971934];
  var c2 = [4052627,3972934];

  var wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137);
  var length = wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(
    ol.proj.transform(c1, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'),
    ol.proj.transform(c2, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'));
  // 833.12 m
```

Answer (score 0):

Distances are tricky. The fact that the map units of a coordinate system are in meters (as epsg:3857) doesn't mean that you can measure distances in meters directly. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections, and look how many of those have the "equidistant" property.

I suggest you use turf.js to calculate accurate geodetic distances: http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_distance.html